# Python crontab not launched

Tags: python, cron

Am using this script to register under /home/myname/   the cron job:

```
myCron = CronTab(user='myname')
job = myCron.new(command='sudo /home/user/project27/scheduler/django_check.py check', comment='check-django')
job.minute.on(0)
job.hour.on(5)
myCron.write()  

for jb in myCron:
    print jb
```

However, after executing this python script to register into crontab,
the script django_check.py does not launch. 
I checked looking at the crontab log.
If I launch manually the script django_check.py, it runs well.

How can I identify the issue here ?

EDIT: 
  A)As mentionned below, it seems the script is launch once and not everyday....
    How to make daily batch

B) Want to configure into Python Crontab, easier for maintenance.

Comment: Is only this particular script not being launched? Other commands in your crontab work fine?

Comment: "The script does not launch"... you mean the `django_check.py` you want to configure on your crontab? Or actually the script that configures it?

Comment: Do notice that you are setting `django_check.py` to run on minute **0** of hour  **5** of every day, so it will run *once*, at 5 am based on your machine's time.

Comment: Is it an issue that you use `sudo` in your command? Are you sure there is no password required for that? Remember that, usually, cron-jobs and external processes run in their "own" shell, and will not have all your PATH settings and aliases set up. The latter may also be an issue if you don't use a standard system Python (like /usr/bin/python, or whatever the hash-bang line of django-check.py points to).

Comment: Your command starts with `sudo`. That means you'll be prompted for your password, but cron commands don't usually run in an interactive shell or terminal.

Comment: Also, why not use `crontab -e` and add the following line to get the same effect: `0 5 * * * /home/user/project27/scheduler/django_check.py check` ?

Comment: Thx for your comments.
I edited my post accordingly.